# How to add app for different Facebook page?

Tags: facebook

I've spent the past few hours trying to figure this out but can't find anything.

Basically I've setup a website for a music festival, I'm trying to integrate Facebook with the site and whenever I create an app it keeps creating it under my personal account.

I am setup as an admin under the music site's Facebook but I still can't figure out how to create an app just for that music site completely separate from my personal account.

Anytime I try to access the developer section using the account it gives me this error:
http://smyl.es/ss/001.png

Comment: That's the way it's supposed to work. People own apps, not pages. You can give admin access for an app to multiple people, just like you can with pages.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design.

I'm assuming the music site is a Facebook page?

While you can log in and use Facebook as the page, rather than yourself, Facebook apps are always owned by a real Facebook user, not a page. So you either need to create the app yourself, or have someone else create the app and add you as a developer.

Comment: Ok thank you for the reply, how can i associate it with that specific page though and keep it separate from my account?  I mean i understand it has to be done under my personal account, but i'm trying to setup a wordpress plugin for feed and like buttons.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, everything you do is associated with your personal account as the developer. However, you aren't supposed to be putting it on your personal page. As the developer, whenever I do anything it shows up in my personal account because I am set up as the developer and admin of all my pages. That's how Facebook wants it. Before, people were setting up different accounts for a business profile and it ended up with lots of businesses as personal accounts instead of business pages with an admin user.

Whenever I do anything with Facebook I have everything available to all the pages, but only one is actually using the app or whatever it is. Does anyone see anything different?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes it is a separate page but that's the only page i want to pull info from.  If i just setup the app and give it permissions i guess my real question is how can i configure my wordpress plugin to obtain information from just that page and not my personal page.  So i guess the REAL question is how do i associate an app with a specific page

Comment: Oh, I think you want your page id. Go to your fanpage, click edit info, look in the URL and you will see id=. Copy everything between that and the ampersand and your app will now konw which page to pull its data from.